# Unresolved reference: fab, and inability to infer a type for parameter view

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I seem to be stuck at the MainActivity.kt file and my app won't debug as it shows the mentioned errors.

This is for a music player app with a Navigation Drawer.
Edit : I have added the layout file after the comment as requested.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
```

//as someone asked for the layout file as well here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/echo_logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: post the layout file

Comment: @JudeOsbertK I have added it

Answer (score 0):

There is no component called fab in your xml layout file. You still have the line of code that access a component called fab from your class. Remove

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
```

It should get it to work.